# 7zip multiple files into multiple 7z files

Tags: windows-7, 7-zip

I have a bunch of files in a directory and want to 7zip each one into its own 7zip archive

So, for example, 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv will end up as 1.7z, 2.7z, 3.7z

Is this possible with a .bat file in Windows 7? I'm using 7zip 9.29 alpha

Comment: Related: [*How to do something to each file in a directory with a batch script*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180741/how-to-do-something-to-each-file-in-a-directory-with-a-batch-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want (well, almost, 1.csv will be 1.csv.7z):

```
for %f in (*.csv) do "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -t7z %f.7z %f
```

If you run this in a batch file you need to change %f to %%f.

Also, if the files `1.csv.7z` already exist in the directory, you need to delete them first.  The following command line should do that:

```
for %f in (*.csv) do del %f.csv
```

Comment: beautiful. needed a slight tweak (for named files, I'd like to keep it as generic as possible so others can use it), but i got it working
------------------

for %%f in (*.csv) do "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -t7z "%%f.7z" "%%f"

Answer (score 2):

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\" -mx=9 -ms=on -md=26 -mfb=256
```

Comment: care to explain what it does?

Comment: thanks, this one is even nicer, much neater output :)

edit: oh erm oops. i think you got the wrong end of the stick, but good effort.

Comment: this is the folder version instead of files. mx9 is max compression. ms is solid archive.